# How to prevent assigning attributes to an object that have not been specified in class definition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

I have defined a simple class. The suprising thing is: I can assign attributes that haven't been defined in the class definition.

1. How is that possible?
2. How can I prevent this from happening?

See here, what I mean, this is my simple class:

```
class Dog:                             
    def __init__(self,name):                
        self.name=name
```

Of course I can now instanciate an object: `dog = Dog('Fido')`

Printing `Print(dog.name)` yields `'Fido'`.

But now I just can assign to my object dog new attributes though I haven't  included them in the class definition.

For example: `dog.mood="happy"` works. When I print `Print(dog.mood)`, I get `'happy'`, that means it works. Why is this **possible** and how can I **prevent** assigning values to attributes like "mood" even though I haven't defined them in my class definition of dog?

Comment: You didn't include a language tag, please do edit the question and include it. I suppose this is python.

Comment: thx for the advise, yes that' right  it's python...

Comment: I'm giving your question an upvote because it is an astute observation on your part, especially for a new contributor.

Comment: Scott, thx for your comment and your upvote, I feel flattered  :-)

Answer (score 1):

By default, a user-defined class allows you to assign attributes dynamically. One way to prevent this is to use `__slots__` in your class:

```
>>> class Dog:
...     __slots__ = ('name',)
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...
>>> dog = Dog('Fido')
>>> print(dog.name)
Fido
>>> dog.mood = 'happy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Dog' object has no attribute 'mood'
```

`__slots__` makes it so your instance no longer carries around a `__dict__` for its namespace, which would be a literal python `dict` object. This makes user-defined objects rather bloated by default, so this makes your objects use less memory, and will optimize attribute access as well (removing the need for a hash-based lookup).

Here is the link to [some documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots)

Comment: Perfect, very helpful - that is exactly what I was looking for,  thx a lot!!